# Stack two sets of data into one in google sheets - different columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am looking for a solution that helps me stack two sets of data (from diff. columns, different order) into one data sets

EXAMPLE:

**columns names + order tables1:**
first name, last name, city, age, gender

**columns names + order tables 2**
gender, frist name, last name, city

Is there any way I can do it in Google sheet?
I've been browsing solution but only found one, when the data has the same order in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays, like this: with a "," you'll set the columns, and with a ";" you'll set row. All that into {}
Try writing:

```
={1,2;3,4}
```

And you'll see this:
[image]

So, imagine you want to stack both sheets, let's say they're named Sheet1 and Sheet2, and go from ColumnA to ColumnE and they go from row 1 to row 100:

> =Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet1!B1:B100,Sheet1!C1:C100,Sheet1!D1:D100,Sheet1!E1:E100;Sheet2!B1:B100,Sheet2!C1:C100,Sheet2!D1:D100,Sheet2!E1:E100,Sheet2!A1:A100}

PS: I observed that there's no age column in Sheet2, but I put "Sheet2!E1:E100" anyway -> you'll need always the same amount of columns if you want to stack them

PPS: You can use ":" if you have adjacent columns. The first part you can simplify it with ={Sheet1!A1:E100;...}

---

EDIT:

Given now your example sheet, I've edited my formula to adapt the column order and included a filter to exclude the empty rows:

> =query({Sheet1!A:E;Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!E2:E,Sheet2!C2:C,Sheet2!D2:D,Sheet2!B2:B},"Select * WHERE Col1 is not null")

[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12RrpLYzOgi_CCKwS8KOZkjCYU2dI5MaAHpyK7P38Dxg/edit#gid=1480571036